# Replace numbers to 3 decimal places using RegEx

Tags: regex, angularjs-directive

I need to replace only numbers that are decimal to 3 places. 
The following example is working fine.
Output look like this:
0.000

But i can type 0..
How can i do only one decimal point (.) 0.000

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('allowDecimalNumbers', function () {  
return {  
    restrict: 'A',  
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {  
        elm.on('keypress', function (event) {  
            var $input = $(this);  
            var value = $input.val();  
            value = value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')    
            if(value == "" && event.which == 46) {
                return false;
            }
            var findsDot = new RegExp(/\./g)  
            var containsDot = value.match(findsDot)  
            if (containsDot != null && ([46, 110, 190].indexOf(event.which) > -1)) {  
                event.preventDefault();  
                return false;  
            }  

            var arrValue = value.split('.');
            if (value.split('.').length == 2) {
                if(value.split('.')[1].length > 2) {
                    event.preventDefault();  
                    return false;
                }

            }   
            $input.val(value);  

            if (event.which == 64 || event.which == 16) {  
                // numbers  
                return false;  
            } 
            else if (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57 || event.which == 46) {  
                // numbers  
                return true;  
            } 
            else {  
                event.preventDefault();  
                return false;  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}});
```

Here is my html:

```
<input type="number" allow-decimal-numbers ng-model="length1" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that validation can cause problem depending on locale, in french decimal separator is `,` and input type="number" prevents `.` to be typed.

could make it working removing code, note that `.` doesn't need to be escaped when it is in a character set ( between `[` and `]`)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);  
app.directive('allowDecimalNumbers', function () {  
    return {  
        restrict: 'A',  
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {  
            elm.on('keydown', function (event) {  
                var $input = $(this);  
                var value = $input.val();  
                if ([8, 13, 16, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {  
                    // backspace, enter, shift, escape, arrows, delete
                    return true;
                } else if ( (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57 || 
                        event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105) && !value.match(/[.,]\d{3}/)) {  
                    // numbers
                    return true;
                } else if ([46, 110, 190, 188].indexOf(event.which) > -1  && !value.match(/[.,]/)) {  
                    // dot and numpad dot  
                    return true;  
                } else {  
                    event.preventDefault();  
                    return false;  
                }  
            });  
        }  
    }  
});
```

Note that a digit can't be inserted after there's a decimal separator followed by three digit but we can't check where the digit is inserted even if it's in front.